# Submitting a job to qsub generates an error, "Warning: no access to tty"

Tags: qsub

I am trying to run a job via qsub.

This is my script:

```
run.sh: 
#/bin/sh
 java -jar project-test-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

This script works fine when I execute it by ./run.sh

Since it prints some result, I want to do this via qsub:

```
./run.sh > output
```

But when I do:

```
qsub -cwd -o output.log run.sh
```

Instead of printing the result in output.log, output.log has the following printed:

```
Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).
Thus no job control in this shell.
```

When I simply do

```
qsub run.sh
```

It only says that the job has been submitted, but doesn't print anything anywhere.

Could you help me figuring out what to do to get the job done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like qsub is not using the `#!/path/to/shell`.
What worked for me is making runwrap.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
bash ./run.sh
```